# Encrypt / Decrypt openSSL between Windows PC and PHP running on Linux Web Server

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, php-openssl

I'm trying to learn how to perform a simple encrypt/decrypt between a Windows 64 machine (my PC) and PHP running on a Linux web server using openSSL.

On my Windows machine, I've installed **OpenSSL v1.0.2k** for Win64 and I'm using the following command to create an encrypted string using a simple password and a simple key located in secretkey.txt.

`enc -aes-256-cbc -A -base64 -nopad -nosalt -pass pass:hello -in secretkey.txt`

When I run the command above, I get the following string:

`3WE7cuBFhuLCn3/ZBnUrBn68nn3tVn0NKKz63B3uvoc=`

Using the string above, I would expect PHP on my Linux web server to be able to decrypt it like this:

```
 $encrypted = '3WE7cuBFhuLCn3/ZBnUrBn68nn3tVn0NKKz63B3uvoc=';
 $enc = 'aes-256-cbc';
 $password = 'hello';
 $key = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, $enc, $password, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING);
 echo $key .' should equal this-1234-is-4567-my-8910-secret';
```

But, instead I get this:

9(j���T]��$�W�Ma��S�è��zz�>.( should equal this-1234-is-4567-my-8910-secret

I've reviewed the following sites and tried multiple versions, but I can't get it to decrypt properly:

[Open SSL Enc](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Enc)
[Open SSL Command Line](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Utilities)
[PHP Decrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php)

Comment: not a duplicate.  the question is about trying to encrypt from the command line (windows) and decrypt using php.  the recommended solution is all about encrypting and decrypting all within PHP.

Comment: Are you base64 decoding the openssl output in your PHP code?

Comment: Zero padding is a poor idea, in general PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding is used. Zero padding will not allow binary data to be encrypted that happens to end with a zero (0x00) byte.

Answer (score 1):

AES requires a *key* to work. This is a sequence of bytes of exactly the exact length (32 in the case of AES-256). You can’t directly use a *password* (unless the bytes that make up the password happen to be the right length).

Furthermore, [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29) requires an *initialization vector* (IV) of 16 bytes.

The OpenSSL `enc` command derives the key and the IV to use from the password provided using an internal function [`EVP_BytesToKey`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html). In order to decrypt a file that has been encrypted with `enc` you need to reproduce this function. The details of the algorithm are in the docs. In PHP, it might look like this:

```
$password = 'hello';

$bytes = "";
$last = "";

// 32 bytes key + 16 bytes IV = 48 bytes.
while(strlen($bytes) < 48) {
    $last = md5($last . $password, true);
    $bytes.= $last;
}

// First 32 bytes are the key, next 16 are the IV.
$key = substr($bytes, 0, 32);
$iv = substr($bytes, 32, 16);
```

You can then use these values in the `openssl_decrypt` command:

```
$enc = 'aes-256-cbc';
$result = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, $enc, $key, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);
```